Tig: remove leading plus/minus from lines in diff
When you look at the diff in Tig, there are already colors, but the + and - symbols are still in front of the lines, making it difficult to copy parts of the diff directly into the editor.
There are many questions and answers on how to do that in Git, but how do you do it in Tig?

I got downvotes. Please take a moment to comment on why you did this. I've been using tig for years; it's a valid and cool app. I have another tig-related question on SO. I did some research, checked their GitHub repo, and even asked ChatGPT before posting it

Okay, 6 downvotes and not a single comment explaining the problem. I've been a SO user for 12 years. Please explain what's wrong here.

Probably impossible at this moment. There's a PR that was opened years ago and is still open for some reason – https://github.com/jonas/tig/pull/901
